# viewing folders named 'public_html'

Tags: apache, wamp, directory

I've just altered wamp to use my external hard drive to use a folder in there as the DOcumentRoot.

The problem being, as all my sites are in seperate folders ie i:/www/sitename/public_html/
the folder public_html is not showing  and I cannot access it. Is there a setting somewhere maybe in the htconf so I can access these folders.

regards

Phil Jackson

Comment: i'm still mad you left the Lakers.

Comment: Just an internet Alias, not my real name, any comments regarding the question?

Answer (score 0):

If your WAMP config has an entry along these lines:

```
UserDir public_html
```

I believe you will have to remove it.  If not, or if that doesn't help, we probably need some more details about your config, and exactly what is happening.